# How to prove a sequence of real numbers is bounded iff its limsup is less than infinity?

Tags: real-analysis

The statement is:

> show a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is bounded if and only if $\limsup |a_n| < \infty$

Can someone please help me with both directions?

Here is a sketch of what I did, but I'm not sure if it is right:

- for one way, I said that the sup's exist, their sequence is convergent, and the $\limsup |a_n| = |\limsup a_n|$. I'm iffy about this last statement
- for the other way, I proved that $\limsup |a_n| < \infty \implies -\infty < \liminf a_n < \limsup a_n < \infty$, which means it must be bounded.

Comment: Can you give a hint on how to prove that statement (1)? I think that is the key thing I am missing in my argument for the first way.

Answer (score 0):

Proof. ($\Rightarrow$) Suppose that the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is bounded. By definition, there is a real number $M$ such that $\vert a_n \vert \leq M$ for all $n \geq 1$. Consider $$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \vert a_n \vert = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sup_{k \geq n} \vert a_k \vert). $$ Let $n \geq 1$. Consider $\sup_{k \ge n} \vert a_k \vert = \sup\{ \vert a_k \vert : k \ge n \}.$ Since $\vert a_k \vert \le M$ for all $k \geq 1$, we also have $\vert a_k \vert \leq M$ for all $k \geq n$. Thus, $\sup\{ \vert a_k \vert : k \ge n \} \leq \sup\{ M : k \geq n \} = M.$ Therefore, $$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \vert a_n \vert \le \lim_{n \to \infty} M = M < \infty. $$

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \vert a_n \vert < \infty.$ Then, $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\sup_{k \ge n} \vert a_k \vert) < \infty.$ This means that $\sup_{k \ge n} \vert a_k \vert < \infty$ for all $n \ge 1$ (Lemma). In particular, $M = \sup_{k \ge 1} \vert a_k \vert < \infty$. By definition of supremum, $\vert a_n \vert \le M$ for all $n \ge 1$. This proves that $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence. $\blacksquare$

$\textbf{Lemma.}$
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\sup_{k \ge n} \vert a_k \vert) < \infty \Rightarrow \sup_{k \ge n} \vert a_k \vert < \infty$ for all $n \ge 1.$

Comment: I don't quite follow your proof for the second way. In particular, $|a_n|$ won't always necessarily be less than or equal to $\limsup$. Consider the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Good comment. I reworked the argument and changed some notation. I believe the statement holds if you accept the lemma. I attempted to include a proof of the lemma but got stuck. Hopefully someone can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

First suppose $\limsup_n |a_n| < \infty$. Then there is $N$ such that $|a_n| \leq \limsup_n |a_n| + 1$ for $n \geq N$. Hence $\sup_{j}|a_j| \leq \max(|a_1|, \dots, |a_{N - 1}|, \limsup_n |a_n| + 1) < \infty$.

Conversely, suppose $\sup_{j}|a_j| < \infty$. Then $\limsup_{n}|a_n| \leq \sup_{n}|a_n| < \infty$.